# Writing a closed interval as an intersection of half-open intervals.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm not sure if this is true or not. I find it very intuitive:

> $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} [n,n+\frac{1}{n^{2}}+\frac{1}{k}) = [n,n+\frac{1}{n^{2}}] $

Is this true and how do I then construct a proof? If the case is that the above statement is false, are there any other ways to express $[n,n+\frac{1}{n^{2}}]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $n+1/n^2+\frac 1k>n+1/n^2$, $\supset$ is true. If $n\leq x< n+1/n^2+1/k$ for all integer $k$, then $x\leq n+1/n^2$. Indeed, if we had $x>n+1/n^2$, then $x=n+1/n^2+\delta$ where $\delta>0$. Now take $k$ such that $\frac 1k<\delta$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: @AlexBecker Right, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

To construct a proof, you need to observe that all the points in $[n,n+\frac 1{n^2}]$ are in every one of the sets on the left, then show that any point outside $[n,n+\frac 1{n^2}]$ is not in (at least) one of the sets on the left.  Points less than $n$ are no problem, so if I give you a point $x$, which is greater than  $n+\frac 1{n^2}$, can you find a specific set on the left that doesn't include it?